# Managing worker memory on a dask localcluster

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to load a dataset with dask but when it is time to compute my dataset I keep getting problems like this:

> WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting.

I am just working on my local machine, initiating dask as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    libmarket.config.client = Client()  # use dask.distributed by default
```

Now in my error messages I keep seeing a reference to a 'memory_limit=' keyword parameter. However I've searched the dask documentation thoroughly and I can't figure out how to increase the bloody worker memory-limit in a single-machine configuration. I have 256GB of RAM and I'm removing the majority of the future's columns (a 20GB csv file) before converting it back into a pandas dataframe, so I know it will fit in memory. I just need to increase the per-worker memory limit from my code (not using dask-worker) so that I can process it.

Please, somebody help me.

Comment: did you modify your `~/.config/dask/distributed.yaml` ?

Comment: You have no idea how much I love you. I had modified distributed.yaml before but I was doing it in the wrong bloody file! Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: no problem, happy computing!

Comment: By the way, I only see options for changing behavior as specific fractions of the memory limit, is there a way to raise the memory limit entirely?

Comment: I ended up using: Client(memory_limit='64GB')

Comment: @Jones  - me too. Then what's the relevance of memory limit - if 64GB is allocated to a single worker. Did you find a way around?

Comment: I actually ended up changing to using dask delayed and distributing my operations with pandas then building up the results in a single dataframe, rather than trying to load everything and manipulate it in one large dataframe. So the issue became moot.

Answer (score 23):

The argument `memory_limit` can be provided to the `__init()__` functions of `Client` and `LocalCluster`.

## general remarks

Just calling `Client()` is a shortcut for first calling `LocalCluster()` and, then, `Client` with the created cluster ([Dask: Single Machine](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/setup/single-distributed.html)). When `Client` is called without an instance of `LocalCluster`, all possible arguments of `LocalCluster.__init()__` can be provided to the initialization call of `Client`. Therefore, the argument `memory_limit` (and other arguments such as `n_workers`) are not documented in the API documentation of the `Client` class.

However, the argument `memory_limit` does not seem to be properly documented in the API documentation of `LocalCluster` (see Dask GitHub Issue [#4118](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4118)).

## solution

A working example would be the following. I added some more arguments, which might be useful for people finding this question/answer.

```
# load/import classes
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

# set up cluster with 4 workers. Each worker uses 1 thread and has a 64GB memory limit.
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=4, 
                       threads_per_worker=1,
                       memory_limit='64GB')
client = Client(cluster)

# have a look at your workers
client

# do some work
## ... 

# close workers and cluster
client.close()
cluster.close()
```

The shortcut would be

```
# load/import classes
from dask.distributed import Client

# set up cluster with 4 workers. Each worker uses 1 thread and has a 64GB memory limit.
client = Client(n_workers=4, 
                threads_per_worker=1,
                memory_limit='64GB')

# have a look at your workers
client

# do some work
## ... 

# close workers and cluster
client.close()
```

## further reading

- https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/local-cluster.html
- https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/4118

Comment: Hi @daniel is memory limit per worker? or the local cluster?

Comment: @sampath.xyz : per worker; see also http://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/worker.html#memory-management